# Error al interntar Web Scraping al atributo src en img

Tags: c#, web, aplicación-web

Estoy intentando aprender ha hacer Web Scraping, he conseguido ya sacar todos los datos menos uno, el atributo src de una imagen(img), lo curioso es que si que saco el alt.

Un fragmento del la web de ejemplo:

```html
<li>
<a href="/ver/49688/steinsgate-0-15" class="fa-play">
<span class="Image"><img src="/uploads/animes/thumbs/2950.jpg" alt="Steins;Gate 0"></span>
<span class="Capi">Episodio 15</span>
<strong class="Title">Steins;Gate 0</strong>
</a>
</li>
```

El fragmento de código que no funciona:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
var Ultimo_animes = Ultimos_Episodios[0].Descendants("li")
                .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("", "")
                .Equals("")).ToList();
foreach (var Ultimo_anime in Ultimo_animes)
            {
                //Imagen
                Console.WriteLine("Caratula: " +     Ultimo_anime.Descendants("img")
                    .FirstOrDefault().GetAttributeValue("src", ""));
        }
```

Si cambio:

```
GetAttributeValue("src", "")
```

Por:

```
GetAttributeValue("alt", "")
```

Si que saca: **Steins;Gate 0**

Pero con src, sale vacio

¿Una ayuda porfavor?

Muchas gracias de antemano y un saludo

Comment: probablemente se deba a algún framework front-end que usan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He descubierto la solución, es una tonteria.
Al sacar por consola todo el html de la web me di cuenta que el atributo src lo tiene puesto como data-cfsrc no se a que se debe pero lo lee así de la web.
Por lo que si uso

```
GetAttributeValue("data-cfsrc", "")
```

Si que funciona, no se a que se debe pero asi si que funciona.
Un saludo